# autofill from inputbox value according to column count

Tags: excel, vba, new-operator, excel-2016

I need to copy down myValue from input box based on another column count.

```
Sub CopyDownValue()
    Dim MyValue As Variant
    Dim LR As String

    LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUP)
    MyValue = InputBox("Enter Sales Month")
    Range("A2").Value = MyValue
End Sub
```

I need a input box value copied down in column A based on row count in column B.

Comment: Will the month be a string? Is there a desired format? Actual date as number? String? 3 letter short hand month (Jan or January)? I ask because you should always validate when giving the user the option to input something. What if they make a mistake and type `juan` into the inputbox?

Comment: Yes the date will be a string, formatted 01-31-2019

Comment: So `Dim MyValue as Date`. Is there any expected date range? What if they put `01-31-1963` OR `01-30-2094`? The point is, allowing inputs opens macros up to user error. You may find it worth while to try to code out some of these errors rather have full faith on the users

Comment: Yes good point. Error handling will be my focus now that I have a working sheet. Ok thank you.  I have a lot to learn here!

Answer (score 0):

You left out the `.Row` in your `LR` calculation.

You should also qualify your objects (in this instance, ranges) with a worksheet. This is done using the `With` block, although there are other ways.

```
Sub CopyDownValue()

Dim MyValue As Variant, LR As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")                                '<--- Update with your sheet name
    LR = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    MyValue = InputBox("Enter Sales Month")
    .Range("A2:A" & LR).Value = MyValue
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "Invalid or unquailifed error"

Comment: Did you update the 3rd line with the correct sheet name? `With Sheets("Sheet1")`?